# InstanceID returns invalid token

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, push

I'm using `GCM` on Android.

I use `InstanceID.getInstance(...).getToken(...)` to receive a push token, but in some cases (after application updates or re-install) I receive an invalid token.

When the server returns a `NotRegistered` error, I've connected with a debugger and called `InstanceID.getInstance(...).getToken(...)`. But this token is not valid (I've tried to send push via `curl -s "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" ...` using this token), I receive `NotRegistered` error.

Why instanceID could return invalid token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.

I worked with `instanceID` from two different threads. I called `getToken(...)` two times simultaneously. If instance doesn't have a cache, it get token from network. I think, it sends two requests in my case and there is no guarantee of it's order. So `instanceID` cached one token, but google cloud another one.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't give invalid token.

Have you applied all procedures?

- InstanceIDListenerService: When the token changes via the app
  updates, etc.
- RegistrationIntentService: When the token changes, you receive it via InstanceIDListenerService and call this intent to get a new
  token.

Comment: I know it shouldn't. Yes, I've made all this procedures.
The most interesting part is getting token via instance id and sending push via gcm to this token, and get notRegistered error. So there is a moment, when instance id returns invalid token

Comment: Is it possible to share your code parts regarding the token? By the way, make sure that you are using the right JSON identifier file.